# Select erro android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Nao to conseguindo retornar o valor dentro do meu arry sempre volta 0

Classe **Read**

```
public class Read {
public ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> getLista() {
SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getReadableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Maindb.TABELA;
ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {

    do {
        RespostasAguaCasa resp = new RespostasAguaCasa();

        resp.setId(c.getInt(1));
        resp.setValoragua(c.getInt(2));
        resp.setAcordarhora(c.getInt(3));
        resp.setAcordarminu(c.getInt(4));
        resp.setDormirhora(c.getInt(5));
        resp.setDormirminu(c.getInt(6));

        lista.add(resp);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    {
    }


}
c.close();
return lista;
}
```

Classe **Update**

```
public class Update {


SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase dbb = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase dbbb = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
public boolean addResposta(RespostasAguaCasa respostasAguaCasa){

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("id" , respostasAguaCasa.getId());
cv.put("valoragua" , respostasAguaCasa.getValoragua());
cv.put("acordarhora" , respostasAguaCasa.getAcordarhora());
cv.put("dormirhora" , respostasAguaCasa.getDormirhora());
cv.put("terceirahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getTerceirahora());
cv.put("quartahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuartahora());
cv.put("quintahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuintahora());
cv.put("acordarminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getAcordarminu());
cv.put("dormirminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getDormirminu());
cv.put("terceiraminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getTerceiraminu());
cv.put("quartaminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuartaminu());
cv.put("quintaminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuintaminu());
return  db.insert(Maindb.TABELA, null , cv)!= -1;
}
Metodos que estou adicionando e buscando

 private void adicionarPessoa() {


RespostasAguaCasa p = new RespostasAguaCasa();

p.setId(1);
p.setValoragua(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.valoragua);
p.setAcordarhora(EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx);
p.setAcordarminu(EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
p.setDormirhora(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxx);
p.setDormirminu(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexx);
p.setTerceirahora(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxx);
p.setTerceiraminu(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxx);
p.setQuartahora(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxx);
p.setQuartaminu(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxx);
p.setQuintahora(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxxx);
p.setQuintaminu(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxxx);
if (new Update().addResposta(p)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Inserido com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao inserir pessoa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
private void verPessoas() {


ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> pessoas = new Read().getLista();

for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++) {
    RespostasAguaCasa p = pessoas.get(i);

    Toast.makeText(this, "gg" + p.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}}
```

Classe **Maindb**

```
public class Maindb extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE = "Projeto";
public static final  int VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABELA = "Aguacasa";

private static Maindb instancia;

public static Maindb getInstancia() {
if (instancia == null) instancia = new Maindb();
return instancia;
}


private Maindb() {
super(Myapp.getContext(), DATABASE, null, VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


@Override
public synchronized void close() {
instancia = null;
super.close();
}
}
```

Se necessario alguma outra informaçao so pedir .

Comment: Já colocou um `Log.d` no seu select, pra ver se vem algo?

Comment: Nao sei usar log tem algum exemplo para que eu possa tentar ?

Comment: Segue a documentação do android [ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log ]

Comment: No caso eu falei colocar no select, mas é onde você está usando o cursor, me expressei errado